# How to fire filter function that's set in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hello i have a filter function that's set in a variable, but want to execute as soon as the user clicks the button. The function enableFilter has to check if the item.id matches the item.category and fire the filter as it is true. Can anyone help me with that? It is not necessary to filter two at a time. Only one filter at a time

Comment: This doesn't look like ordinary JavaScript, it looks like a framework. Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Is `enableFilter` a function or a variable containing a flag? You're using the same name for both, that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can store your filter condition id in a state variable, like this:

```
const [selectedItemId, setSelectedItemId] = useState(null);
```

Then change your filter cases based on **selectedItemId**, like:

```
const filteredCases = i18n('casesOverview.cases').filter(category => selectedItemId ? category.category.includes(selectedItemId) : true)
```

then update the button **onClick** props with **setSelectedItemId** as follows:

```
{i18n('casesOverview.categories').map((item, key) => (
              <ButtonOutline
                onClick={() => setSelectedItemId(item.id)}
                id={item.id}
                key={key}>{item.label}</ButtonOutline>
            ))
}
 <GridWideColumn>
     {filteredCases.map((item, key) => (
                <CardBrand
                  key={key}
                  text={item.teaser} href={item.link}
                  image={<Image src="" srcSet={item.coverImage} alt="" />}
                  brandImage={<Image src={item.clientLogo} alt="" />}
                  link={item.link}
                  client={item.client}
                  textInfo={item.category}
                />
      ))
     }
```

Comment: And how am i suposed to use const filteredCases outside the function for mapping?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve actually?

Comment: Yeeah i added some more code to it. I have buttons (categories) with id's. And i have cases with categories. Now when the user clicks the button, it has to filter on the cases with the matching category

Comment: Yeah but is the function enableFilter  now unnecessary? And unfortunately it doesn't work. When I log the const filteredCases. It logs all the cases

Comment: Yes, you don't need enableFilter fn now. Besides, I have updated the filter function to filter cases properly.

Comment: And i think this:  `onClick={() => selectedItemId(item.id)}` has to be `onClick={() => setSelectedItemId(item.id)}`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214895/discussion-between-user3771096-and-aadil-mehraj).